# nginx - port forwarding to another container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx container which will be used to port forwarding communication to other containers such as Ansible/GIT/Jenkins etc ....

When using [nci-ansible-ui](https://hub.docker.com/r/jc21/nci-ansible-ui/) as Ansible, I can reach the Ansible UI using the external host server IP http://10.97.98.6:3000 (which is according the instructions). Yet, when trying to use the nginx to port forward to this container - the 404 and 502 errors appear in the log while the web page is not properly loaded... note that in such case, I would like to use http://10.97.98.6/Master_Ansible as the URL. Note that http://172.18.0.5 is the docker network IP given to the container...

```html
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  warn;

    root /etc/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    #charset koi8-r;

   location / {
    root /etc/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /$uri $uri/ =404;
   }

    location /Master_Ansible {
        proxy_pass         http://172.18.0.5:3000;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout      150;
        proxy_send_timeout         100;
        proxy_read_timeout         100;
        proxy_buffer_size          8k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

}
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: what are the IPs given to both containers: Ansible and Nginx? are they on the same docker network?

Comment: Both containers are on the same docker network and each container has it's own IP. 
nginx - 172.18.0.4
Master_Ansible - 172.18.0.5

Comment: when running `docker run...`, did you expose port 80 for nginx container? and could you remove `listen       3000;`?

Comment: 1) I used -p 80:80 2) did and not helping...

Comment: Try to add trailing slash to proxy_pass : proxy_pass         http://172.18.0.5:3000/;

Comment: By some reason trailing slash is not visible in my comment above. It should be `proxy_pass 172.18.0.5:3000/;`

Comment: Not helping ...